# How to Adjust index when doing array splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a photo manager that breaks in the view when I delete an index that is NOT the last index

Model:

```
var array = [{id:1, img:"index0"},{id:2, img:"index1"},{id:3, img:"index2"}]
```

if i do..

```
array.splice(0);
```

index 1 and 2 will be hidden, so when I investigated i learned that index 1 and 2 doesn't adjust to index 0 and 1, that's probably the reason why it's breaking in the view since i'm using a ng-repeat, how do i workaround this issue.

```
  <div class="col" ng-repeat="pic in pics track by $index">
    <img ng-click="delete()" ng-src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/sample/posts/{{pic.id}}/{{pic.img}}.jpg"></img>
  </div>
```

controller:

```
//HTTP REQUEST --> for brevity i didn't include the service
    $scope.delete = function(){
    PostService.DeletePic()
      .success(function (data) {
     $scope.pics.splice(index);
              }).
            error(function(error,status) {

          }) 
    }
```

Comment: When are you doing `array.splice(0);` and please add controller code as well

Comment: Ok this is confusing. Do you have `var array` or do you have a `$scope.pics`?

Comment: those are just samples sorry the context should be pretty clear

Comment: @teddybear123 Ok, but I think you got your answer. You miss a necessary parameter in the `splice` method.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `array.splice(0);` will not remove any element from the array.

> Syntax: `array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`
>
> `deleteCount` An integer indicating the number of old array elements to remove. If deleteCount is 0, no elements are removed. In this case, you should specify at least one new element. If deleteCount is greater than the number of elements left in the array starting at start, then all of the elements through the end of the array will be deleted.
>
> (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

You need to call `array.splice(0, 1);` to remove the first element. This should fix your 'index not adjusting' problem.